# failed validation results in form values being cleared + validation errors are not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a rails novice so hopefully this will be an easy one. Here is what I have:

**models/school.rb**

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
end
```

**models/course.rb**

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  validates_presence_of :grade, :subject
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
map.resources :schools, :has_many => :courses
```

**views/courses/new.html.erb**

```
<% form_for [@school, Course.new] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

**courses_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
    @course = @school.courses.new(params[:course])
    if @course.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Course was successfully created.'
      redirect_to(@school)
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        # bug: form clears and no validation error messages are displayed
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

When the validation fails, the `new` action is rendered but the form values are cleared and I don't see any validation failure messages. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

In your courses_controller.rb have you created

def new

```
@course = @school.courses.new()
```

end

and in your form you have to mention

<% form_for [@school, Course.new] do |f| %>

<%= f.error_messages %>

...

<% end %>

Thats why your error messages are not appeared in you form

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where the error messages will display in your view.
**views/courses/newhtml.erb**

```
<%= error_messages_for 'course' -%>
<% form_for [@school, Course.new] do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: You left us the "s", but "error_messages_for" worked to display the validation errors, but it did not prevent the form fields from being cleared.